# Why do I need to write std::ios::sync_with_stdio inside main?

Tags: c++, gcc, std

If I write :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

main(){
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);

    cout << "hi";
}
```

Then, the program compiles correctly, but if I write:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

ios::sync_with_stdio(false);

main(){
    cout << "hi";
}
```

then GCC produces the following error:

> error: specializing member 'std::basic_ios::sync_with_stdio' requires 'template<>' syntax
>            ios::sync_with_stdio(false);

What does this error mean, and how to correct it (if possible)?

Answer (score 3):

If you write the line `ios::sync_with_stdio(false)` outside of main(), the compiler interprets it as a function declaration. It then complains about the missing `template<>`

To call the function you would need to write something like this:

`bool result = std::ios::sync_with_stdio(true);`

To redefine the static function, you would need to write something like this:

```
bool std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(bool sync)
{
  //do something
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct it to

```
std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
```

or for a particular stream like `cin`, you can

```
cin.sync_with_stdio(false);
```

And it is supposed to be inside a function since it is an expression not a statement.